# Output text in between two words

Tags: php, search

I would like to use PHP to input a certain text and the output should be the text in between two words. To clarify:

Input:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Output:

```
dolor sit
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
$word1 = 'ipsum';
$word2 = 'amet';
preg_match('/'.preg_quote($word1).'(.*?)'.preg_quote($word2).'/is', $str, $match);
// result would be in $match[1]
```